# Automatically scale text up as large as possible to fit within certain page count

Tags: fontsize, scaling, size, resize, scale

Using [relsize](https://ctan.org/pkg/relsize)'s `\relscale{<scaling factor>}`, is there a way to automatically set the scale so that text is as large as possible but producing a document no more than a specified number of pages?

Comment: this would take several runs of latex trying different font sizes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, I figured so, ∵ it only knows the page count at the end of the rendering process.

Comment: and tex doesn't hold the document in memory so by the time it knows that the first pages have already been typeset and gone, it can't go back all it can do is write a hint to try a smaller or larger font next time

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So it seems I'd have to write a script to do "several runs of latex trying different font sizes"…

Comment: @Geremia: Indeed. Not only that, each selection of font sizes may require multiple compilation itself, as they layout may change enough to have `\label`s and `\ref`s change, not to mention the ToC/LoF/LoT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Python script](https://github.com/Geremia/relscale) accomplishes it:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Automatically scale text up as large as possible to fit within certain page count
# https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630429/36603

import os, sys

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage example: " + sys.argv[0] + " in.tex max_num_pages tolerance")
    exit()

texinput = sys.argv[1]

s_prev = 0; s = 1 #previous and current scale factor
Δs = float(sys.argv[3]) # tolerance
f = 2 # ∈ (1,∞)
p_max = int(sys.argv[2]) # max number of pages

print("%s\t%s\t%s" % ("relscale", "Δ rescale", "pages"))
while True:
    os.system('sed -i \'s/\\\\relscale{[0-9.]\+}/\\\\relscale{' + str(s) + '}/\' "' + texinput + '"')
    p = int(os.popen('xelatex "'+ texinput + "\" | grep -o '([0-9]\+ pages)' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'").read().strip())
    print("%f\t%f\t%d" % (s, abs(s-s_prev), p))
    if abs(s - s_prev) < Δs and p <= p_max: # break when scale factor s within Δs tolerance
        break
    s_prev = s
    if p <= p_max:
        s *= f
    elif p > p_max:
        s /= f
    f = (1+f)/2

#run again to update references that may have changed
os.system('xelatex "'+ texinput + '"')
```